# SQL Server : using MERGE statement to update two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, merge

I am trying to use a `MERGE` statement to update 2 tables using a single source (CTE). It works when I use only 1 merge, but when I add the 2nd one, it returns an error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure mn_SeoUrl_UpdateBulk, Line 46
>   Invalid object name 'cte'.

Is it possible to update 2 tables with a merge? If it is possible, I am doing it incorrectly and I hope someone can show me what is the correct method of doing this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is my failing code (false col names):

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
    SELECT
        [u].[col1], [u].[col2], [u].[col3], 
        CASE                                        
           WHEN [u].[col1] LIKE 'L%' 
              THEN 'c/' + [u].[col2] + '/' + [u].[col3]
           WHEN [u].[col1] LIKE 'M%' 
              THEN 'm/' + [u].[col2] + '/' + [u].[col3]
        END [col4]
    FROM
        (SELECT
             [st1].[col1], [st1].[col2], [st1].[col3]
         FROM
             [dbo].[sourcetable1] [st1]
         INNER JOIN 
             [dbo].[sourcetable2] [st2] ON [st1].[ID] = [st2].[ID]
         WHERE
             [pd].[col2] <> 0) [u]
)
MERGE [dbo].[table1] AS [Target]
USING [cte] AS [Source] ON [Target].[ID] = [Source].[ID]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET [Target].[col] = [Source].[col]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([col])
    VALUES ([Source].[col]);

MERGE [dbo].[tabl2] AS [Target]
USING [cte] AS [Source] ON [Target].[id] = [Source].[id]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET [Target].[col] = [Source].[col]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([col])
    VALUES ([Source].[col]);
END;
```

Comment: That is because a cte drops out of scope at the end of the statement. Your cte no longer exists for your second merge. Either convert that to a temp table or a table variable or define your cte again.

Comment: CTE's are *temporary* views.  They are only in scope for a single query.  That's their purpose in life.  You can't apply it to two queries.  To do what you want to do, you might want to create a temp table and drop your results in there

Comment: Understood, I will replace the CTE with a temp table and try it again.

Comment: General purpose tip: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`. A tool well worth having in your pocket, though it may not help in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to update 2 tables with a merge?

No, it is not possible to update two tables with a single merge.   You have to do two separate merge statements.

And as others have pointed out in comments, a single CTE can only be used for one statement, so if you do two merge statements, they can't share the same CTE.   My suggestion would be to use your CTE query to populate a table variable.  Then you can use the same table variable in two merge statements.